# Chaining Tasks with async/await

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I've been trying to learn how to use the TPL for quite some time now.
Basically I'm trying to fire off a group of Tasks, wait for them to complete and then fire off another group of tasks, waiting for them to complete before firing off the tasks that update form elements on the UI Thread.

Here's what I got. I think I'm probably overcomplicating it however it does seem to work as I want it too.
Please could I have some advice on how I could simplify this based on what I want to achieve?

```
private async Task PrepareData()
{
    Task[] FirstTasks = new Task[] { TaskOne(), TaskTwo() };    // Do First group of Tasks
    await Task.WhenAll(FirstTasks); // Wait for First group of Tasks

    Task[] SecondTasks = new Task[] { TaskThree(), TaskFour() }; // Do Second group of Tasks
    await Task.WhenAll(SecondTasks).ContinueWith(c => // Wait for Second group of Tasks 
        {
            GuiTaskOne();
            GuiTaskTwo();
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());  // Then update the form on the UI Thread
}

private async Task TaskOne()
{
    someVariable = await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
}

private async Task TaskTwo()
{
    someVariable = await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
}

private async Task TaskThree()
{
    someVariable = await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
}

private async Task TaskFour()
{
    someVariable = await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
}

private async Task GuiTaskOne()
{
    someControl.Text = await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
}

private async Task GuiTaskTwo()
{
    someControl.Text = await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
}
```

Comment: I presume `DoSomething()` is just a method that runs something like `Thread.Sleep(1000);`?

Comment: It could be. I'm using the above code in a real world scenario. The FirstTasks Task array does a couple of Active Directory lookups where the the SecondTasks Task Array uses the information gathered from AD to populate SQL databases. The GUI tasks report progress/information. Thanks

Comment: I think you'd get a better review and more useful comments if you posted your *actual* code - at least the names for `TaskThree` and `GuiTaskOne` (and the others).. right now it looks like all tasks call the same `DoSomething` method. I *know* in reality it's probably not the case, but since reviewers can comment on *any aspect of your code*, it'd be nice if your code wasn't too narrowed down on the `async/await` mechanics.

Comment: Have a search on TPL Dataflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simplify Gaz's code even more by using the fact that `WhenAll()` is a `params` method:

```
private async Task PrepareData()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(TaskOne(), TaskTwo());

    await Task.WhenAll(TaskThree(), TaskFour());

    GuiTaskOne();
    GuiTaskTwo();
}
```

Also, depending on what the `Task` methods actually do, there might be a better way than having them set a field, but that's hard to tell from the example code.

Answer (score 8):

Since `await` is effectively a continuation anyway, you could simplify your function to:

```
private async Task PrepareData()
{
    Task[] FirstTasks = new Task[] { TaskOne(), TaskTwo() };    // Do First group of Tasks
    await Task.WhenAll(FirstTasks); // Wait for First group of Tasks

    Task[] SecondTasks = new Task[] { TaskThree(), TaskFour() }; // Do Second group of Tasks
    await Task.WhenAll(SecondTasks); // Wait for Second group of Tasks 

    GuiTaskOne();
    GuiTaskTwo();
}
```

I also suspect you meant to await the GUI tasks too.

Answer (score 5):

```
await Task.WhenAll(Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)), Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)), Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
            .ContinueWith(_ => Task.WhenAll(Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)), Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)), Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))))
            .Unwrap();
```

Note that it is important to call `Unwrap` when your action returns `Task<Task>` rather than `Task<TResult>`.

The above statement should take 10 seconds. Without `Unwrap`, it would take 5 seconds because it will not 'await' for the second group to complete.